# Sort object by another object value inside

Tags: actionscript-3, sorting, apache-flex, actionscript

Here some complication sorting in my application.

Now i have data object is like following(called `pCList`):

```
Object[0]:
  Id: 1
  comp: Test
  med: xyz
  condition: valueObject.Condition

Object[1]:
  Id: 2
  comp: Test1
  med: pqr
  condition: valueObject.Condition

Object[2]:
  Id: 3
  comp: Test
  med: abc
  condition: valueObject.Condition
```

`condition VO` Have data like:

```
condition data1:
  conId: 001
  cond: abcds

condition data2:
  conId: 001
  cond: trdfd  

condition data3:
  conId: 001
  cond:  dsdsds
```

For normal sorting i will do as following way;

```
var sort:ISort = new Sort();
var sortField:ISortField = new SortField("med");
sort.fields = [sortField];

if(pCList != null)
{
    pCList.sort = sort;
    pCList.refresh();
}
```

In which `pcList` is sort by med.

But now, I want to sort by `condition.cond`

 like first come which have `cond` value  `abcds` then `dsdsds` then trdfd and so on...

I Have tried it using:

```
var sort:ISort = new Sort();
var sortField:ISortField = new SortField("condition.cond");
sort.fields = [sortField];
```

But not succeed. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ISort` has a property `compareFunction`, that can be used for custom sorting. See example below.

```
var sort:ISort = new Sort();
sort.compareFunction = function(a:Object, b:Object, fields:Array = null):int {
    var conditionA:String = a.Condition.cond;
    var conditionB:String = b.Condition.cond;
    if (conditionA < conditionB) {
        return -1;
    } else if (conditionA > conditionB) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
};
```

Comment: Yeah. That's working pretty good. I think it's not possible But good to know this new function. Thank you.